# Why is it impossible to make a monopole magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles

I know that some string theories estimate that the mass would have to be way higher than what we can produce, about a Planck mass. But I also read that scientists have actually created a monopole magnet in a lab but it is not found in nature. How to make this consistent. What is that I'm missing? Why should the magnetic field of a spinning electron be dipole? And what exactly at the basic level is the difference between electric and magnetic fields?

Comment: Nobody has made an actual magnetic monopole in a lab, but they have *simulated* a monopole, using a Bose-Einstein condensate. See https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.030401 "The vorticity in the condensate coincides with the magnetic field of a magnetic monopole, providing an ideal analogue to the monopole studied by Dirac."

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261246/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95962/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Why don't these questions come up in the "similar questions " bar when I'm typing